C# - WPF - DataGrid - Share bindings amongst columns
I bind an instance of this class to a DataGrid
public class SomeClass
{
    public int m_width { get; set; }
    public int m_height { get; set; }
    ...
    public string[] m_content { get; set; }
}      

The first columns display data as is
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Width" Binding="{Binding m_width}"/>
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Height" Binding="{Binding m_height}"/>

For the last column, I need to display m_content and I use ItemControl to iterate over it
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Value}" Foreground="Black">
    <DataGrid.Columns>

        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Width" Binding="{Binding m_width}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Height" Binding="{Binding m_height}"/>
        
        <!--custom grid column-->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>

                    <!-- iterates over array of strings -->
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding m_content}">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>

                                    <!-- how to add binding to other fields ? -->
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}"></TextBlock>

                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>

                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

But how can I bind all m_width/m_height fields to the TextBlock ?
<TextBlock Text="{Binding .}" Width="{Binding m_width}" Height="{Binding m_height}" ...></TextBlock>

I tried to use relativesource
<TextBlock Text="{Binding .}" 
    Width="{Binding m_width RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}" 
    Height="{Binding m_height RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}" ...>
</TextBlock>

But nothing works, no matter the Mode or the AncestorType I use.
Thanks for your help

Perhaps AncestorType should be ItemsControl and Path should be DataContext.m_width.

ItemControl deals with m_content array, so I need one of the parent holding the whole class with the other fields

The DataContext of ItemsControl holds exactly the whole class with the other properties.

The reason why it does not work as easy, is that the DataTemplate within the ItemsControl only gets the one element of the ItemsSource set to the ItemsControl. To enable the possibility to access to m_width and m_height you need the access to the element "above" the current one.
An easy way to do that could be to access directly to the ancester, for example using a name.
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding m_content}" x:Name="MyItemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <StackPanel>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.m_width, ElementName=MyItemsControl}"></TextBlock>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.m_height, ElementName=MyItemsControl}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>


You took the right path, but you didn’t quite reach its completion.
You are correctly searching for the ancestor "Row" (but you can also search for the ancestor Cell), but you have not correctly specified the path to the property. An instance of SomeClass is not the row itself, but its Data Context, so the correct path is "Binding DataContext.m_width, RelativeSource=...".
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" 
    Width="{Binding DataContext.m_width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}" 
    Height="{Binding DataContext.m_height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}" ...>
</TextBlock>

Please note that I have specified a different "DataGridRow" and "DataGridCell" ancestor in each binding, but both methods work correctly and the same.
It is also not necessary to specify the path "." to bind to the current context. "Empty" Binding will do this by default.

I also thought of this but personnally had several times performance issues using RelativeSource. But it works good as well.

I finaly achieved what I wanted, thx to @emoacht
<TextBlock Text="{Binding .}" 
    Width="{Binding DataContext.m_width RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" 
    Height="{Binding DataContext.m_height RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}" ...>
</TextBlock>

